# Emulated Numpad Mapping - Numpad Period?

Tags: customization, shortcut

By trial and error I have found that in Blender v2.7 on a laptop with emulated numpad set, <kbd>\</kbd> represents <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> (forward slash).

Which key represents <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (period)?

Answer (score 13):

In emulated numpad mode there isn't a non-numpad key that's mapped to the same functions as numpad period.  The way to get a key to do what numpad period does is to map your own choice of key to do the same things as numpad period does.  Numpad period is mapped to "View Selected" in eight or more windows (you can find them by searching for key-bindings for 'numpad' and scanning through the results but searching for 'numpad .' doesn't work).  The window in which I use numpad period most often is the 3D view.  Below is an explanation of how to remap the numpad period key in that window. A similar process would work for any other window type you want to remap.

I [used this explanation](http://www.versluis.com/2016/05/how-to-use-the-view-selected-shortcut-in-blender-on-a-mac/) to change the key binding in user preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) for the *View selected* command under *3D View*> *3D View (Global)*> *View Selected* (see below, I have mapped it to semicolon <kbd>;</kbd>).

[image: Remapped 'View Selected' command]

Before you pick the key to map it to, you might like to make sure that your new binding isn't used for some other command. You can search by key by changing *Name* in the top search bar to *Key-Binding* and enter the key you'd like to check.  If nothing shows up (see screenshot) then you're safe; if some bindings show up you might still be ok if none are applicable to the 3D view.

[image: Searching for Key-Binding 'Question Mark' finds no matches]

Rather annoyingly, searching for 'period' <kbd>.</kbd> *doesn't* find the bindings to numpad period - not even if you type the period with a numpad - but you can get close by searching for the key-bindings for 'numpad' (type in the word as though it was a key).

If you feel adventurous, you might prefer to add an additional binding rather than removing the numpad binding (maybe you'll buy a numpad one day). To do that, take a look at the command you would have remapped by clicking the little white triangle:

[image: Expanded 'View Selected' command]

That shows the command is `view3d.view_selected`.  Scroll way down to the end of the list of bindings and find the *Add New* button. Press it and you'll get a new binding called *none* just above the button you clicked:

[image: New Binding]

Expand the key binding, enter the command and set the key you want bound to it:

[image: New binding filled out].

Finally, **don't forget to save your user preferences**!

Comment: Remapping key binding for the action in Outliner won't ever work in viewport since this is entirely different context - 3D viewport and Outliner, as well as different shortcuts. Answer above as well as question never mention about *View Selected* command for the viewport (it could be for clarity). *View Selected* command can be found in Key-Binding mode by searching for "numpad" in 3D View context (maybe a limitation or a bug since some shortcuts seem to be available for search).

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated my answer to explain how it is an answer to the original question and to explain how to search (as far as is possible) for bindings to numpad period.

Comment: Nice and detailed answer!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

I was also bothered by this a lot. The only way I found is to change the binding to a laptop key that is recognised by Blender.

Go to the user prefs, Input and in the search field, write <kbd>.</kbd> and you will find the binding called Outliner Show Active. Change it to something that works on your laptop.

[image: key binding for outliner.show_active]