# how to put a object in blender in focus? Viewport focused on the Selected Object

Tags: camera, image

how to put a object in blender in focus? Viewport focused on the Selected Object

i click on emultating mouse pad, saved changes. everything works besides the "period" to focus, idk what im doing wrong

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYj6e-72RDs
10:13-10:38

can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you mean how to move tha camera, so that the object is in the frame? Or do you mean focus as in not blurry because the camera is focusing at a different distance?

Comment: i want to focus on the selected subject so that its in frame

Comment: You want to pivot around an objects origin, that is what you want, not focus, you are not talking about the camera

Answer (score 2):

Are you hitting period on the number pad? If your keyboard doesn't have a numpad this thread may be useful in remapping the key:

[Emulated Numpad Mapping - Numpad Period?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/emulated-numpad-mapping-numpad-period)

Comment: yes hitting period on the number pad. but i dont have one so i select "emulate number pad" and then i click "." on my camera to focus on it as a short cut while i have it selected. but it does nothing. also im not sure what the function is called so when i try to remapping the key i get lost, because blender has so many setting function names and shortcuts. so i am not able to locate the function to be able to remap

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is View Selected. It can be found in the Viewport in View > View Selected, or via spacebar/F3 search. You can change the Shortcut but right-clicking that button and selecting change shortcut.
Also Emulate Numpad seems to only work with the numbers and the - sign for me. I am using a german keyboard layout so that might be part of the problem