# Expand the selection on mac keyboard

Tags: shortcut, selection-tools, osx

How can i expand the selection on mac keyboard ? there is no plus sign on my mac keyboard.

Comment: Hello, not the exact same question but this might help : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/emulated-numpad-mapping-numpad-period also you can do it with Select > Select More / Less > More (or Less)

Answer (score 0):

*User Preferences > Input > Keyboard* and enable **Emulate Numpad**.
Use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> to *Select more*.